# Users who frequently ask then answer their own question

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I just noticed [this user's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/997474/curious1) profile, after reading a really simple question asked by them and wondering why someone with almost 1000 rep would ask something so basic (it could have been solved with a simple Google search or SO search...[this is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23704749/regular-expressions-in-razor-the-type-or-namespace-name-match-could-not-be-fo).

Looking at this profile, every single answer this user has ever posted was to his/her own question. I understand that accepted answers to your own questions don't earn rep and that if it's a useful question to others it does have a place on SO, but to me it seems that if you can answer so many of your own questions you probably shouldn't be posting them in the first place.

Is this acceptable behavior for SO?

Comment: If the questions or answers are bad, downvote them. If they are duplicates or otherwise off-topic, close them. If that's not the case, fair enough.

Comment: Given that we are trying to be a source of great questions and answers, the how we get there is less important than actually getting good content. That's without considering the issue and cost of duplication.

Comment: That question you linked doesn't actually have anything to do with what you're asking, correct?

Comment: Given that it is actually OK for users to ask and answer their own questions, ***this question*** can be improved by making the title more descriptive about the cases when such questions and/or answers warrant a downvote and/or a close-vote. The title in its current state is kind of vague.

Comment: accepted answers to your own questions *do* earn rep. You just don't get the +15 for the acceptance.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ah true. You don't get that either!

Comment: Fail:  there was a incident today where a user answered his own question and got down votes on both question and answer!  It's probably inappropriate, but it gave me a jolly giggle.

Comment: If the question and the answer are good and not duplicates, then it adds something useful to SO that wasn't there before. So it should be acceptable if done well.

Comment: Did the question have -7 votes before you asked your question?

Comment: Why shouldn't the user post those? I've had times where asking a question was all I needed to realize the answer. What if that's what this user is doing, and it just happens that SO is his [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Comment: You made a mistake linking to his question. I believe this was the actual question posted by Curious1 about Razor C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917001/razor-asp-net-c-how-to-validate-a-form-field-that-is-required-and-allows-htm

Comment: What do you think about cases like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/comprehensive-explanation-for-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-errors ? When user obviously already have answer prepared as he submits the question.

Comment: @NiematojakTomasz nothing wrong with answering your own question if it can be useful to others.

Answer (score 46):

I personally think it's undesirable to **not** do what this user is doing.

I haven't done an exhaustive search over all his answers quite yet, but it appears as though he's figuring out the answer to his own questions, and posting that as the answer.

This is very useful to any future user who would stumble across his question in a google search and would also want to know what the resolution is.

I make it a point to always accept a correct answer to my questions when I feel that the question is resolved, If there is no correct answer to be found, I post my own to let future users know what the resolution is.

Comment: Self-answer questions are harmless **as long as they're useful, and not duplicates**. I can see situations where users, in an attempt to gain rep, post trivial questions about trivial problems, thereby swamping [main] with low-quality junk.

Comment: @Cupcake This isn't the blog-post question issue that you seem to think it is.  Maybe this user shouldn't be asking these questions in the first place, but it definitely is a good thing that he's posting what the resolution is after he's already found an answer

Comment: @Cupcake They're much better than harmless-- They _help_ people.

Answer (score 28):

This behavior is not "frequent." He's posted 138 questions in two and a half years, of which he answered (if what you say is correct) 17. His rep is currently 929, which does not reflect any kind of effective strategy over two years. He looks to me like an average guy.

Even if he were doing this on purpose, there's no problem. Self-answered questions are not inherently different. If the question or answer is bad, it will receive downvotes. Chosen self-answers are not listed first by default, presumably to avoid some forms of arrogance, but that's not what we have here. The several answers I checked all add something to the discussion and come from his own experience in solving the problem.

Comment: +1 Maybe he is asking too soon or maybe he is figuring out his problem as he tries to explain it to the rubber duck. Either way, it's fine.